# Since Android Studio gradle used for the building I can not find the "old" Module Settings window to set my libraries

Tags: android, android-studio

Where i can find this window?

[image]

I just get this window when I click on project structure.

[image]

Is this a bug or i am just to stupid to find it again?
I'm sorry for  the URLs, but I cannot upload any images yet

Comment: I've discovered the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old Module settings pane has been removed for Gradle projects (it's still available for using classic IntelliJ Android projects). The old Module settings didn't work properly with Gradle-based projects (it didn't output its changes to build.gradle), whereas the new one does the right thing.